# cakephp 3 upload photo with Josegonzalez/Upload

Tags: cakephp, upload, cakephp-3.0

I want to have some photos for my products and tried to use :

```
Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload
```

but I have some problem with this .
The field that I specified for image is became required .

and this is the error I get when leave the field empty :

> This field cannot be left empty

when comment the  `Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload` configurations that field is became optional as it should be !!

this is my configuration :

```
$this->addBehavior('Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload' ,
            [
                'image' => [
                    'path'              => 'webroot{DS}img{DS}dynamic' ,
                    'nameCallback' => function ($data) {
                        $ext = pathinfo($data['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        return rand(100000,999999).time().rand(10000 , 99999).".".$ext;
                    } ,
                    'keepFilesOnDelete' => false,
                ] ,
            ]);
```

I also deleted default validation for the field in the table but it doesn't work.

thanks a lot for your help

**UPDATE :**
This is the input  for the photo field before submit

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
    <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">

    </div>
    <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 10px;"></div>
    <div>
                <span class="btn default btn-file">
                    <span class="fileinput-new">chose pic</span>
                    <span class="fileinput-exists"> edit </span>
                    <input value="" name="..." type="hidden">
                    <input name="image" id="image" image="" height="150" width="200" type="file">
                </span>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn red fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> حذف </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is after i hit submit and the page refreshes with error "This field cannot be left empty"

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
    <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
        <img src="{my directory}/products/add?error=4&amp;size=0" alt="">  
    </div>
    <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 10px;"></div>
    <div>
                <span class="btn default btn-file">
                    <span class="fileinput-new">chose pic</span>
                    <span class="fileinput-exists"> edit </span>
                    <input value="" name="..." type="hidden">
                    <input name="image" required="required" id="image" val=" 4   0" class="form-error" image="<img src=&quot;/Jobs/website/mohammad_parsa/admin/products/add?error=4&amp;amp;size=0&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;/>" height="150" width="200" type="file">
                </span>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn red fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> حذف </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does _empty_ mean in that context? An empty string? And "empty" file upload array? And what validation rules are you applying to the field?

Comment: it means an empty upload file .I deleted all validation rules so nothing ( no validation rule )  and the error that i receive it is not ajax ( like the one you get by adding require to the validation rules . it appears after page reloads ). I update the question with the generated input field before and after  i  submit the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
  $validator
        ->allowEmpty('image');
```

adding the code above to the table will solve the problem.